# google spreadsheet query COUNT()

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm able to return data using the formula below:

```
=ArrayFormula(Query(importRange("SPREADSHEET_KEY", "Sheet1!A1:z2500"), "Select Col8, COUNT(Col8), SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) WHERE Col8 is not null GROUP BY Col8 order by SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) desc))
```

This returns all possible rows. What I'm trying to achieve is to return data only if `COUNT(Col8) >= 5`

I've tried :

```
=ArrayFormula(Query(importRange("SPREADSHEET_KEY", "Sheet1!A1:z2500"), "Select Col8, COUNT(Col8), SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) WHERE Col8 is not null and COUNT(Col8) >=5 GROUP BY Col8 order by SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) desc))
```

as well as

```
=ArrayFormula(Query(importRange("SPREADSHEET_KEY", "Sheet1!A1:z2500"), "Select Col8, COUNT(Col8), SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) WHERE Col8 is not null GROUP BY Col8 order by SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) desc"), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 >= 5")
```

Both returned errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which errors were returned?

Comment: The 1st returns COUNT is not allowed in WHERE while the 2nd returns ArrayFormula takes only 1 argument but finds 2

Comment: Put a FILTER() around your formula, filtering by the COUNT column

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong in the second formula. Encase the first query with a second one:

```
          =ArrayFormula(QUERY(Query(importRange("SPREADSHEET_KEY", "Sheet1!A1:z2500"), "Select Col8, COUNT(Col8), SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) WHERE Col8 is not null GROUP BY Col8 order by SUM(Col24)/COUNT(Col8) desc"), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 >= 5"))
```